# Data failed to sync to API endpoint

Tags: laravel, post

I'm currently using Laravel Artisan console command (app:sync-data) to synchronize data from a local database to API endpoint. Uses Laravel's Http facade to send a POST request to the API endpoint.

But there is problem syncing the data.

**Code :**

```
private function sendDataToApi($log)
{
    try {
        static $counter = 0;
        $counter++;

        $apiEndpoint =  '//urlhere';
        $apiToken = '//tokenhere';

        $data = [
            'CardNo' => $log->CardNo,
            'DateIN' => $log->DateIN,
            'TimeIN' => $log->TimeIN,
            'DateOUT' => $log->DateOUT,
            'TimeOUT' => $log->TimeOUT,
        ];

        $jsonData = json_encode([$data], JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    
        $this->info("Payload sent to API (Set $counter) ". "for CardNo: " . $log->CardNo ."\n". $jsonData);

        $response = Http::withHeaders([
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $apiToken,
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
         ])->post($apiEndpoint, ['json' => $jsonData]);

        if ($response->successful()) {
            $this->info("Data sent to API (Set $counter). Response: " . $response->body());
        } else {
            $this->error("Error sending data to API (Set $counter): " . $response->body());
        
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $this->error('Error sending data to API: ' . $e->getMessage());
}
}
```

**Error :**

[image]

```
Payload sent to API (Set 830) for CardNo: 4698
[
    {
        "CardNo": "4698",
        "DateIN": "2023-12-19",
        "TimeIN": "19:25:08",
        "DateOUT": "",
        "TimeOUT": ""
    }
]
Error sending data to API (Set 830): {"message":"Employee 
attendance created failed","error":"No matching employee records 
found - "}
```

Comment: The code as shown is working fine (posting the data to the API). The API is returning an error: "No matching employee records found - ". Based on the information you sent the API, the API couldn't find an employee record. If you have control over this API endpoint, you'll need to start there to determine why it didn't find an employee record with the data you passed into it.